# What does the clause "when they tip the balance between two already available technologies" mean?

Tags: meaning

Take carbon-pricing first. Long cherished by economists (and The Economist), such schemes use the power of the market to incentivise consumers and firms to cut their emissions, thus ensuring that the shift from carbon happens in the most efficient way possible. The timing is particularly propitious because such prices have the most immediate effects **when they tip the balance between two already available technologies.**

Comment: If there are two *different* technologies available (in this case, to address the problem of reducing carbon emissions) then **IF** some implementation of a solution (carbon-pricing, here) gives enough of a cost advantage to one technology over another to tip the balance in  favour of using it, this will have a big effect. But I have to say this isn't a very meaningful observation. All it seems to be saying is ***competitive pricing is effective if it tips the balance*** (and by implication, price changes are *ineffective* if they *fail* to shift the market).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you so much for your detailed answers every time!